# scala.MatchError: null for all requests after some timepoint

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.4

I have a fairly large Play Framework application running Play 2.4.3 in production. I've had a few instances where suddenly all requests to the server start getting the following MatchError:

```
! @6p4o8d49h - Internal server error, for (GET) [/bookings/desk/suggest-products?term=&maxSize=50&page=1] ->
play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception[MatchError: null]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:261) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.throwableToUsefulException(DefaultHttpErrorHandler.java:169) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(DefaultHttpErrorHandler.java:131) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.j.JavaHttpErrorHandlerAdapter$$anonfun$onServerError$1.apply(JavaHttpErrorHandlerAdapter.scala:22) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.j.JavaHttpErrorHandlerAdapter$$anonfun$onServerError$1.apply(JavaHttpErrorHandlerAdapter.scala:22) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.j.JavaHelpers$$anonfun$invokeWithContext$1.apply(JavaHelpers.scala:140) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.j.JavaHelpers$$anonfun$invokeWithContext$1.apply(JavaHelpers.scala:139) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.j.JavaHelpers$class.withContext(JavaHelpers.scala:151) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.j.JavaHelpers$.withContext(JavaHelpers.scala:160) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.j.JavaHelpers$class.invokeWithContext(JavaHelpers.scala:139) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.j.JavaHelpers$.invokeWithContext(JavaHelpers.scala:160) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.j.JavaHttpErrorHandlerAdapter.onServerError(JavaHttpErrorHandlerAdapter.scala:22) [com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:158) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$9$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:155) [com.typesafe.play.play-netty-server_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:216) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:216) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.executeScheduled(Execution.scala:109) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:71) [com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:23) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:39) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:399) [com.typesafe.akka.akka-actor_2.11-2.4.0.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
Caused by: scala.MatchError: null
    at play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:97) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:105) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:104) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146) ~[org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:103) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:96) ~[com.typesafe.play.play_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:524) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:560) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:536) ~[com.typesafe.play.play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

Before the first error occurs the logs look quite healthy and normal and the first exception is some random request. After the first request to hit this error, all subsequent requests get the same error until we restart the server.

From looking at `play.core.j.JavaAction.apply(JavaAction.scala:97)` it looks like the error means the returned Response objects are all `null`.

I looked at some graphs of the heap space usage from the time when this happened and there is a huge spike in memory usage. I strongly suspect the MatchErrors are hiding OutOfMemoryError("Java heap space") errors.

Is there a way I can stop the scala.MatchError from hiding the actual OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: Looks like there is an error in your actions but the framework is not showing you the real problem. Have you implemented your own error handler? https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaErrorHandling  or https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/GlobalSettings

Comment: Yes I have my own HttpErrorHandler implementation. As far as I can tell it was able to both send a report of these errors to a tracking system, and show the users an error page where they could report the error to our support system.

Comment: Could the Match error be created in your error handler? That could hide the original error. If you are experiencing a memory leak, I can only suggest that you stress your app in a test server and remove your error handler in this server. Another option could be to do remote debugging on a failing production server once is not accessible by your users.

Comment: Had the exact same problem a couple of hours ago(together with the mem spike). Any follow up on this? Did you manage to identify the source of the problem?

Comment: The MatchError is simply caused by the the JVM not being able to allocate memory to make a match. What I eventually did was change the parts causing OOME to properly release memory. As far as I know play still has the problem of running in to MatchError when heap space fills up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by a combination of the heap being full, and Scala needing to allocate heap to do pattern matching.

The solution is to fix whatever is causing the OutOfMemoryException, the MatchError is a red herring. It's just a side effect of running out of heap space.

Comment: Thanks for posting this. How did you manage to overcome the framework hiding the OOME? I have no custom error handlers, yet that part of the stack is missing.

Comment: To clarify, I have not managed to overcome the framework hiding OOME at all. I have just learned that the MatchError is just a side effect of the OOME preceding it.